# Vim sometimes prints :.,.+1e to command line instead of :e

Tags: vim

I'm not sure what exactly I'm pressing to get this, but sometimes when I make a certain mistake typing `:e` then `:.,.+1e` appears in the command line instead. What is it, is this notation useful anywhere and what is the help section on this syntax? I have some plugins installed, it may appear because of those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You typed `2:e`. This produces a range before e on the command line.

`:.,.+1` mean the current line plus 1 more line. (or over the range of 2 lines).

```
. means the current line
.+1 means 1 line below the cursor.
```

You should take a look at [`:h range`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#%3arange)

Answer (score 3):

You are specifying a range to use with the command line, in this case you hit `2:e`. The `.,.+1` applies the command to both the current line (`.`) and the next line (`.+1`). For the `:e` command, it will just say `E481: No range allowed`, but commands that take a range will use it, just as if you highlighted then in `v`isual mode before typing the command.

You can see more on this with `:h range` and `:h [range]`.